# kubernetes kube proxy mode(which one IPVS,iptables or userspace)

Tags: kubernetes, iptables, kube-proxy, userspace, ipvs

how can i check if my kube-proxy is run in IPVS mode?

kube proxy run in three diffrent mode, but my question is how to check in which mode my kube-proxy is runnig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my question is how to check in which mode my kube-proxy is runnig?`

You can check at the beginning of kube-proxy log for the mode that is currently in-effect:

```
...
xxxxx date/time xxxxx       1 server_others.go:180] Using ipvs Proxier.
```